# Can I invoke a main method passing jvm parameter?

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

My intent is that I want to debug something of hadoop.
The command to run the hadoop program is :

```
bin/hadoop jar path/to/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /wordcount /output
```

And this command will call the RunJar.java 's main() method .
I could pass jvm parameter to RunJar.java 's main() method by add these in hadoop-env.sh :

```
HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9000"
```

But the code inside RunJar.java 's main() is :

```
ClassLoader loader =
  new URLClassLoader(classPath.toArray(new URL[0]));
Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(mainClassName, true, loader);
Method main = mainClass.getMethod("main", new Class[] {
  Array.newInstance(String.class, 0).getClass()
});
main.invoke(null, new Object[] { newArgs });
```

Can I pass some jvm parameter (`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999`) to this invoke method

```
main.invoke(null, new Object[] { newArgs });
```

So that I could debug the main method invoked by RunJar.java in remote way

Answer (score 0):

No, the JVM is already started.

The only way is if you run your JAR by starting a new JVM using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` classes.

This would probably do the trick, and you woudn't need to pass the arguments since you can actually call the script:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "bin/hadoop jar path/to/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar " +
        "wordcount /wordcount /output");
```